# The import org.apache.poi.ooxml cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm getting this error for 3.17, even though I successfully added the dependency

```
 <dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
 <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
 <version>3.17</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
 <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
 <version>3.17</version>
 </dependency>

 </dependencies>
```

and imported the file poi-ooxml-3.17 to my build path. Any idea what else I need to do?

Code line that fails is

```
import org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper;
```

but part that is highlighted is everything before util.SAXHelper;

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried version 4.0.0 of `poi-ooxml`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To expand, `org.apache.poi.ooxml.util.SAXHelper` doesn't exist in 3.17, but exists in 4.0 as @deHaar pointed out.